# Markov Inequality Bound less than 4/3

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_1,...,X_{20}$ be independent Poisson random variables with mean 1.

Then the question asked to find the bound for $P(X_1+...+X_{20}>15)$. By using Markov inequality, i get $P(X_1+...+X_{20}>15)\leq\frac{E(X_1+...+X_{20})}{15}=\frac{20}{15}=\frac{4}{3}$. Am I doing anythng wrong or is it possible for the answer to be like this?

Comment: The bound you have got is correct but of no use!

Comment: so is there any other way to reduce the bound ? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: The sum of independent Poisson RV is still Poisson, write your probability as $1-P(X_1+\cdots+x_{20}\le 15)$ and you get an explicit (maybe sufficiently nice for your problem) expression!

Comment: @user52227, but the question requires me to find $P(X_1+...+X_{20}>15)$ only (which i feels weird. ) In fact, by using CLT, i get the probability is 0.8846.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me: "... the question asked to find the bound ...", what do you mean by "the"? There are several, like 2, 3, $\pi$.

Comment: it requires me to find the upper bound of this probability $P(X_1+...+X_{20}>15)$ with each $X_i$ has a mean of 1.